# How to both split and stack bars in a histogram, only hatching the lower bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Imagine that I have the following 6 arrays:

```
A0 = np.array([0,2,5,6,3,1,9,3,5,7])
B0 = np.array([5,1,6,7,3,8,2,3,4,7,1])
C0 = np.array([3,5,7,7,8,5,5,6,7,1,6])

A1 = np.array([2,2,6,7,4])
B1 = np.array([1,6,1,4,0])
C1 = np.array([5,3,3,7,0])
```

I could plot the first three in a histogram, splitting the three arrays into three small bars (blue for A0, yellow for B0 and green for C0).

```
plt.hist([A0,B0,C0])
plt.show()
```

I could also stack the histograms of two arrays; e.g.

```
plt.hist([A0,A1], stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Link to a sketch of the two above histograms]

Now I wish to combine these two effects: I'd like to create a histogram that plots arrays A0, B0 and C0 separately into these smaller bars, and then I would like to have histograms of arrays A1, B1 and C1 stacked on top of the histograms of A0, B0 and C0 respectively.

Preferably, I would also like to have the arrays A1, B1 and C1 be hatched, e.g.

```
plt.hist(A1, hatch='//')
```

while A0, B0 and C0 are just regularly filled and not hatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, is to first draw a split histogram for `[A0+A1, B0+B1, C0+C1]`. These bars will have the same height as stacked bars would have. Then, in a second pass the split histogram for `[A1, B1, C1]` is drawn at the same place. It is important that the same `bins` are used in both cases. Note that this approach will not work for a 'density' histogram.

The code below uses 'paired' colors, drawing the upper part in the darker version, and the lower part in the lighter version and hatched.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A0 = np.array([0,2,5,6,3,1,9,3,5,7])
B0 = np.array([5,1,6,7,3,8,2,3,4,7,1])
C0 = np.array([3,5,7,7,8,5,5,6,7,1,6])
A1 = np.array([2,2,6,7,4])
B1 = np.array([1,6,1,4,0])
C1 = np.array([5,3,3,7,0])

# bar_colors = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']
bar_colors_0 = plt.cm.tab20c.colors[0:12:4]
bar_colors_1 = plt.cm.tab20c.colors[1:12:4]

_, bins, _ = plt.hist([np.concatenate([A0, A1]),np.concatenate([B0, B1]),np.concatenate([C0, C1])], color=bar_colors_0)

plt.hist([A1,B1,C1], bins=bins, hatch='//', color=bar_colors_1)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or do you need something else?